# How to Add class parent of radio button LI tag in angular?

Tags: jquery, angular

**i'm looking for help converting this jquery code to angular**

```
if($('#radioid li input:checked')){
 $(this).parent().addClass("active_radio");
}

$('#radioid input').on('change', function(){
   $("#radioid li").removeClass("active_radio");
   if($('input:checked')){
    $(this).parent().addClass("active_radio");
   }
});

<ul id = "radioid">
   <li><input type="radio" name="color" >red</li>
   <li><input type="radio" name="color" >blue</li>
   <li><input type="radio" name="color" >green</li>
</ul>
```

i want this jquery code to angular for using ts file

Answer (score 0):

You need ngClass and ngModel for your problem. `[(ngModel)]` will bind the radio button value to color and `[ngClass]` to dynamically add your class.

```
<ul id = "radioid">
   <li [ngClass]="{'active_radio': color.value === 'red'}"><input type="radio" name="color" value="red" [(ngModel)]="color">red</li>
   <li [ngClass]="{'active_radio': color.value === 'blue'}"><input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" [(ngModel)]="color" >blue</li>
   <li [ngClass]="{'active_radio': color.value === 'green'}"><input type="radio" name="color" value="green" [(ngModel)]="color" >green</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add value="example", (change) event, and ngClass with the radio input in your app.component.html page

```html
<ul id="radioid">
  <li [ngClass]="activeColor=='red'? 'active_radio': ''">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" (change)="handleRadioChange($event)">red
  </li>
  <li [ngClass]="activeColor=='blue'? 'active_radio': ''">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" (change)="handleRadioChange($event)">blue
  </li>
  <li [ngClass]="activeColor=='green'? 'active_radio': ''">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="green" (change)="handleRadioChange($event)">green
  </li>
</ul>
```

2. Add this code in your app.component.ts page for handling the radio button change event and add or remove class

```js
   

 public activeColor: string = '';
 handleRadioChange(event) {
   this.activeColor = event.target.value;
 }
```